# Ngrx how to test a guard

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to test this simple guard
both canActivate and canLoad
How can manage it ?
I did my first step manage the injected store

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {
    constructor(private store: Store<AuthState>) {}

    canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.store.pipe(
            select(selectIsAuthenticated),
            map(isValidToken => {
                if (!isValidToken) {
                    this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }),
         take(1)
       );
    }

    canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.store.pipe(
            select(selectIsAuthenticated),
            map(isValidToken => {
                if (!isValidToken) {
                    this.store.dispatch(new Logout());
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }),
            take(1)
        );
    }
}
```

My first step

```
export const authReducer: ActionReducerMap<{}> = {
  status: {}
};
describe('AuthGuard', () => {
  let store: Store<{}>;
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [StoreModule.forRoot({}).forFeature('auth', authReducer)],
      providers: [Store, AuthGuard]
    });
    store = TestBed.get(Store);
  });

  it('should ...', inject([AuthGuard], (guard: AuthGuard) => {
    expect(guard).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

But what about testing canActivate and canLoad ?
I've to mock the select and how ?

Comment: I don't know enough about Angular to walk you through mocking the select function. Nor can I tell from your code sample where the select function comes from. But the Angular documentation includes content on using mocks in testing. Is the documentation insufficient for your purposes? Or do you need help making sense of the documentation? The link: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check comments in the code. To test such classes you don't need TestBed.

```js
describe('AuthGuard', () => {
    let guard: AuthGuard;
    let store: Subject<any> & any;

    // because it's a simple class and
    // we don't test templates, inputs, outputs etc,
    // we can use simple objects.
    beforeEach(() => {
        // mocked store can be a simple BehaviorSubject.
        store = new BehaviorSubject({});
        // and we need a spy of course
        store.dispatch = jasmine.createSpy('dispatch');
        // now we can create guard
        guard = new AuthGuard(store);
    });

    // don't forget to kill subscriptions.
    afterEach(() => {
        store.complete();
    });

    describe('canActivate', () => {
        it('logouts on an empty token', () => {
            // setting store state we want.
            store.next({
                authFeatureName: {
                    isLoggedIn: false,
                }
            });

            // toBeObservable comes from https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-marbles
            // it's an awesome tool to test rxjs
            // we expect that canActivate will emit false and close the stream - take(1).
            expect(guard.canActivate()).toBeObservable(cold('a|', {
                a: false,
            }));

            // also we need to check that an action was dispatched.
            expect(store.dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Logout));
        });

        it('returns true on valid token', () => {
            // setting our store.
            store.next({
                authFeatureName: {
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                }
            });

            // check that it emits true now
            expect(guard.canActivate()).toBeObservable(cold('a|', {
                a: true,
            }));

            // and that it doesn't dispatch any actions.
            expect(store.dispatch).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```